# using google sheet functions inside google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made this google script:

```
    function quadrato(input) {
      return POW(input,2);
    }
```

I entered a call to my "quadrato" function in a sheet, but the sheet gave me this error:

> ReferenceError: "POW" non definito. (riga 2).

sheet calling my script function "quadrato"[image]

Instead "POW" is a referenceable function from sheets, as you can see in this iimage:

[image]

Comment: You **cannot** use sheets functions inside apps script.

Comment: Thanks. That's a pity!

Comment: There are equivalents in JavaScript like [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)

Comment: I uset Math.pow but google sheet said to me: Errore
ReferenceError: MATH is not defined (riga 2).

Comment: ok, i success with Math.pow. My problem is solved, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you just need to declare your [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions):

Add /** ... */ statement in front of the function(){}

```
/**
 * Your description about this function.
 * @customfunction
 * @param {input} the description about this papameter
 */
function quadrato(input) {
  return Math.pow(input,2);
}
```